# Printing lines containing a word in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am writing a `script` and I  have in the input 3 arguments - `folder name, type file, word`.
I want to search in the `folder name` in any `type file` and output the lines in those files that containing the word.
For example if in the `folder_name` I have those files: `image.png con.txt file.jpg` and the input is `./MyScript.sh folder_name txt hello`  and `con.txt` contains:

```
hey hello world
hola maybe ha
othello
```

The `output` will be:

```
hey hello world
```

I begin to write this:

```
find $folder_name | sort d| #Check if the word is in the line | while read file_name; do
    cat "$file_name.$type_file" | # Print the line with the word
```

But I don't know how to check in every line the word and then print it.

Comment: See the man-page for `grep` , in particular the options `-w` and `-F`.

Comment: Your script uses a variable named `file_name`. Where does it get the value from? Is this also an input parameter, like `type_file` and `folder_name`? If so, please descibe this in your question, just as you did with the other input parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just run a `find + grep` command like this:

```sh
folder="$1"
ext="$2"
word="$3"

find "$folder" -type f -name "*.$ext" -exec grep -wFnH "$word" {} +

# or to get sorted output:
find "$folder" -type f -name "*.$ext" -exec grep -wFnH "$word" {} + |
sort -t: -k1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not working to me, are you sure about this code?

Comment: 100% tested and working. Now please clarify `not working` and provide details of the error you're getting

Comment: Thanks, it's working, but if I want to go through the files in the folder in lexicographic order I need to add `sort` in the code? What I need to add to the code to make it working?

Comment: I need to write `find "$folder" -type f -name "*.$ext" | sort | -exec grep -h "$word" {} + | sort -t: -k1` , like this?

Comment: So what is the true syntax?

Comment: @anubhava : Since the OP needs to find **words**, which are provided **literally**, I think it must be `grep -nwFH "$word" {}`. Your solution prints lines, which contain somewhere a substring matching the regex stored in `word`.

Comment: @user1934428: Yes good point, I have edited it now.